# Why does a script without she-bang can be run?

Tags: shell-script, linux-kernel, shebang

As far as I understand, to make kernel `execve` a non-ELF file, the file must be a script started with a she-bang `#!`, but I have a script run successfully without it, why does this happen?

```
xtricman⚓ArchVirtual⏺️~ls a.sh -l
-r-xr-xr-x 1 xtricman users 23 9月  26 18:45 a.sh
xtricman⚓ArchVirtual⏺️~cat a.sh
echo "FDHDSFHGFKJJHGO"
xtricman⚓ArchVirtual⏺️~./a.sh
FDHDSFHGFKJJHGO
```

This `a.sh` script doesn't contain a she-bang, so how does it run?

Comment: Your current shell interprets it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file does not start with a "shebang" line, most shells will attempt to execute the lines in the file themselves.

Comment: Can I disable this behavior of bash?

Comment: The shell will only do this on files marked "executable".  If you don't want to execute the file then remove the `x` flag (`chmod a-x a.sh`)